# Can we write a java virtual machine using any language?

Tags: java, bootstrapping

Can we write a java virtual machine using any programming language like c# etc?

Can we write JVM in java language?

Comment: Yes. Some one can answer those questions.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why you couldn't write a JVM in the programming language you choose, be it C# or JAVA *(but not sure why you'd do that)*

Comment: Absolutely. They're turing-complete, after all.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are many different JVM implementations. See [Wikipedia's List of Java virtual machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) for a list of a lot of them.

[Jikes RVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jikes_RVM) is a JVM written in Java which does not require another Java JVM to run. [IKVM.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IKVM.NET) includes a .NET implementation of a JVM.

Answer (score 2):

C# code itself runs in a kind of virtual machine of Microsoft , so if u write some another virtual machine using c# then it will give very bad performance in the case of speed. So better go for C/C++ ,these languages are used for writing such applications.The code generated using c compiler's are almost equivalent to the code using asm.

Definitely you can write virtual machines ...

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do it, but should we do it? It would be slow. Such things as virtual machine better to write in C/C++

Comment: Why should it be slow just because it's implemented in C#? It might well be faster, depending on how it's implemented.

Comment: Because native code is faster than code that runs on virtual machine (such as C#)

Comment: A common misconception, and who says that the machine need be virtual?  Do note, that you're comparing with an implementation that *already* relies on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but if you write it in Java, it will have to run inside another JVM (possibly another copy of itself running inside yet another JVM, and so on).

Comment: Which is pretty much reason enough to do so! And, like all horrible sins against nature, it has already been done! (M-JVM is one I found after a quick Google search)

Comment: You forgot the GNU compiler for Java, which can produce native (x86) code.  So you could write your JVM in Java, compile it to an executable, and then use it to run other Java programs.